# Active Directory (LDAP) query or filter to get users with closed mailboxes?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

I use Exchange 2003 and I have been searching a lot and found related queries like

```
(&(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(msExchHomeServerName=*)(objectClass=User))
```

Which enumerates disabled user accounts with mailboxes, but what I want is quite the opposite, user accounts (enabled or disabled) with CLOSED mailboxes. Thanks beforehand for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Exchange and Active Directory are separate, if user is created on AD doesn’t mean that it will have mailbox account too but usually both are used together.

You can use any LDAP browser like JXplorer or LDAPadmin to check the settings for your users on Active Directory. You will find disabled users on AD moved to different OU or there should be some attribute which will differentiate it from active users.

You can export LDIF file (by LDAP browser like LDAPadmin) for one active user and one disabled user and compare both to find relevant attribute for disabled entity and use it for your query filter. You can consult your IT team also who is managing Active directory for more details. HTH :)